How Postgres creates the SQLException message and will the message always start with keyword "ERROR"
The project on which I am working has recently moved from using Informix to Postgres. A client that is using one of the APIs has is using the exact error message of the SQLException for some sort of validation. The only difference between the messages thrown by the driver of the two database is that Postgresql is adding "ERROR:" to the start of the message. Here is a sample Error message:
ERROR: insert or update on table "bonus" violates foreign key constraint "bonus_cust_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (cust_id)=(1998) is not present in table "customer"

I have been debugging org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl to check where the query execution fails to check how the error message is created, but haven't found it yet mainly because the driver is first changing the  query, message  to byte array at some places and then decoding that. I see that the below code from PGStream class creates the error message, but that is the last step in message creation.
public EncodingPredictor.DecodeResult receiveErrorString(int len) throws IOException {
        if (!this.pgInput.ensureBytes(len)) {
            throw new EOFException();
        } else {
            EncodingPredictor.DecodeResult res;
            try {
                String value = this.encoding.decode(this.pgInput.getBuffer(), this.pgInput.getIndex(), len);
                res = new EncodingPredictor.DecodeResult(value, (String)null);
            } catch (IOException var6) {
                res = EncodingPredictor.decode(this.pgInput.getBuffer(), this.pgInput.getIndex(), len);
                if (res == null) {
                    Encoding enc = Encoding.defaultEncoding();
                    String value = enc.decode(this.pgInput.getBuffer(), this.pgInput.getIndex(), len);
                    res = new EncodingPredictor.DecodeResult(value, enc.name());
                }
            }

            this.pgInput.skip((long)len);
            return res;
        }
    }

Later I found this source https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1136 reading which it gives me some idea of how the message is created. referring below code snippet directly from the source:
ereport(ERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_SYNTAX_ERROR),
        /* translator: first %s is typically the translation of "syntax error" */
                 errmsg("%s at or near \"%s\"", _(message), loc),
                 lexer_errposition()));

I have a couple question:

Will the error message always start with "ERROR:" or there is some sort of configuration that can make it WARN, DBUG etc(I am guessing if it signifies some sort of logger level)
Referring the source above, is https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7d81bdc8c0ce838efa248928065e9b2da829f981/src/backend/parser/scan.l#L1145-L1149 the class that creates error message?
If 2.) is not true, then can anyone help me to find the exact class/method in postgresql-42.7.3.jar that creates the error message.

Thanks !

Using psql:  select 1/0; ERROR:  division by zero. This is coming from Postgres. See When to log: Table 20.2. Message Severity Levels to see what the prefix corresponds to.

Yes, I checked that documentation. If I understand correct, the severity level can be changed by superusers, and in that case, "ERROR" might change to INFO(one of severity levels) ?

No. log_min_messages can change what is the minimum level of message that will be logged. In other words if you set log_min_messages=INFO then all messages of INFO level and above will be logged. It will not change the message level an ERROR level message will always be that.

Seem like a question for https://superuser.com/.

@AdrianKlaver understood. thanks! can you please check question 2.) and 3.) and reply if you have any knowledge on those.

If the message is coming from the database the JDBC is only passing them and 2) and 3) are moot questions.

As to 2), no. That is the parser code for scanning which per Parser README: scan.l  break query into tokens . As to 3) messages are created by the Postgres server and as it is written in C there are no classes. One place to look is src/backend/utils/error. Basically errors are generated as needed by the various parts of the server code.

ok understood @AdrianKlaver. thanks!

@AdrianKlaver is there a way to override the toString() of ServerErrorMessage and remove SEVERITY part being added to the error string? I created a class and extend ServerErrorMessage and then override the toString() in my class, but that class is not getting executed. (did something like @ Override public String toString() )

I don't know as I don't use Java or JDBC. You might try asking on the Postgres JDBC mailing list.

ok ok .. thanks.
